# Sniffing TLS/SSL communication with Wireshark, possible?

Tags: tls, sniffer, wireshark, sniffing

I am trying to snif a SSL/TLS communication and thought about doing it with Wireshark. I've tried to do it and sniffed some with TLSv1.2 protocols, is that the communication? If so, how do I identify and show the messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Chrome both support logging the symmetric session key used to encrypt TLS traffic, and therefore, can also be used to decrypt using Wireshark.

Here is a link that explains how to do this in detail and with ease: [Decrypt Browser Traffic with Wireshark](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/)

> If so, how do I identify and show the messages?

Simply filter your results (assuming you are able to decrypt at this point).