# Decrypting a TLS/SSL traffic with Wireshark

Tags: tls, sniffer, wireshark, sniffing

I am trying to decrypt a TOLS/SSL traffic with Wireshark. When I start the sniffer I do get some packets with TLSv1.2 protocols but I can't decrypt them. Have seen this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138549/sniffing-tls-ssl-communication-with-wireshark-possible), but the tutorial provided didn't solve my problem, which is I can't decrypt it. I don't have the tab "Decrypted SSL Data". It doesn't appear

Comment: You are not describing what you are doing detailed enough. Especially it is unclear if you provide the encryption  keys properly. Please add more detail to your question so that one can find out what might cause your problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I just followed the tutorial provided, and assumed it would work. So I haven't done anything besides that

Comment: Was the session key log file actually created? Can you manually check the content to see if any keys are logged? If the application you're trying to capture does not use OpenSSL, the environment variable will have no effect either.

Comment: @user126290: Either the tutorial is wrong (which I doubt) or you followed the tutorial too loosely and inadvertently did an import step slightly different. But it is impossible to see what you did wrong if you don't describe what you did exactly.

Comment: there are more than one links to guides in the Link that you provided. are you referring to the one in the Answer?

Comment: @JOW Both links are the same

Comment: if i want to decrypt TLS on the fly, I'd go for FIDDLER or Developer tools(press F12 in most browsers) and not Wireshark